# Cluster point vs limit point in net

Tags: general-topology, nets

In topological space $X$, the cluster point $s$ of a net $S$ is that $S$ is frequently in every neighborhood of $s$. It is obvious that if $s$ is a cluster point of $S$, then it is the limit point of it, is the converse true?

---

In Kelly's book, it states that the collection of cluster points of $S$ is exactly the intersection of the collection of limit points of $A_n$, where $A_n=\{S_m|m\geq n\}$. However, I don't think it solve the problem.

Comment: We always have $m \geq m$, so $M = \varnothing$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks

Comment: But what you wrote isn't quite correct. It must be adherent points, not limit points, $$\{x \in X : x \text{ is a cluster point of } S\} = \bigcap_{n\in D} \overline{A_n}.$$

Comment: My understanding is that in a metric space it is true but not in general.  A limit point says that for every neighborhood there is *at least* one point other than the point itself in every neighborhood.  A cluster point is an infinite number of points in every neighborhood.  In a metric space for every point $ne$ to x we can find infinite smaller neighborhoods that must have other points, hence infinite, hence cluster. But in a non metric space that isn't T1 it's possible to have limit points with only finite other points of the set in them.

Comment: @fleablood A cluster point of a net is something different from a cluster point of a set. It's a bit unfortunate that the same term is used for these different things, but that's how things are. The fact that the set of cluster points of  a net is the intersection of the closures of the tail nets is true in all topological spaces.

Comment: @89085731 "the limit point of it", what do you mean by that? The limit point of a net? (and is this different from the limit of a net?); it's not true that a cluster point of a net is a limit of a net (the reverse of course does hold).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I mean limit point $a$ of a net is that for every neighborhood of $a$ there exists point of net in it.

Comment: @89085731 That is a pretty useless notion. You either consider points $a$ such that the net is *frequently* in every neighbourhood of $a$ (a cluster point of the net), or such that the net is *eventually* in every neighbourhood of $a$ (a limit of the net). Just intersecting every neighbourhood is pointless, really.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I see what u mean since net is just a tool thanks

Comment: @89085731 For example: take the reals, usual topology. Take an index set that is 2 copies of the natural numbers, the first ordered before the second. The first copy maps to the rationals (in some enumeration), the second maps to the points $\frac{1}{n}$. Then $0$ is the only cluster point but all points of the reals are "limit points" in your definition.